# Tensorflow android feed with specific array

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I created a CNN model on tensorflow with input placeholder - [None, 32, 32, 3]`tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 24, 24, 3])`. Then I want to use that model in Android application and for that reason I froze the model. When I include the library I noticed that I can feed only with two dimensional array or ByteBuffer. How can I feed the bitmap from the camera? Do I have to change the input size of the placeholder and what should the size be? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using TensorFlowInferenceInterface in Android. I have sample code to feed a sample in Android using TensorFlowInferenceInterface.

Answer (score 0):

`tensorInferenceInterface.feed("the_input", pixels, batch_size, width, height, dims);` 
hope this will work for you